# screen rotation in android

Tags: android, rotation, screen

I want to use screen rotation in android device.
But I don't want to rotate whole activity.
How is this possible to rotate only some of views in a activity

Like there are two button and one ImageView.
I want to rotate only ImageView on screen orientation change.

Plz suggest the way.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is how you disable landspace http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2014/06/activity-screen-rotationorientation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another xml file with same name and put it in new folder inside res/ folder. Name that new folder layout-land. and change in your xml file according to your requirements. It will automatically change the layout file when the orientation will be changed.